# HttpClient authentication -

Tags: java, http

I am trying to emulate this behavior in java

```
curl -u usrname:password http://somewebsite.com/docs/DOC-2264
```

I am not sure if the auth is NTLM or Basic. I login to the website giving a username and passoword. It's a form post.  Using the curl command above I am able to login and get the content.

To do this in java I did:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://somewebsite.com/docs/DOC-2264");
        String authStr ="username:password";
        String encodedAuthStr = Base64.encodeBytes(authStr.getBytes());
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        onnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" + encodedAuthStr);

        InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in   = 
            new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }           


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I only get the login page. Not the actual content. 
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can see the exact header `curl` is sending by adding the `-v` (verbose) option.
2. The `Authorization` header needs the authentication type before the base64 encoded username/password.  It should look something like this: `Authorization: Basic dXNybmFtZTpwYXNzd29yZA==`

Comment: I changed my post to reflect that. I tried the -v option and saw that it's using basic auth.

Comment: It also sets a cookie:                                              < Cache-Control: no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Set-Cookie: jive.user.loggedIn=true; Path=/;HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: jive.server.info="serverName=x:serverPort=80:contextPath=:localName=localhost.localdomain:localPort=9001:localAddr=127.0.0.1"; Version=1; Path=/;HttpOnly

Comment: You need a space between Basic and your username/password

Answer (score 0):

Maybe curl just does the equivalent of this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://username:password@somewebsite.com/docs/DOC-2264");
```